# Using vue-router "history" mode but still need the /#/ in URL in order to work

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using Vue with Webpack and I'm having some trouble with vue-router. I would like to remove the /#/ from the URLs and for that, I'm using "history" routing mode as suggested in several other publications. However, I can't put the fragment URLs to work like the `http://localhost/other/thing`.

For example:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import ThingPage from 'pages/Thing'
import OtherThingPage from 'pages/OtherThing'
import ViewerPage from 'pages/Viewer'
import NotFoundPage from 'pages/404Page'

const routes = [
      {
        path: '/',
        component: ViewerPage
      },
      {
        path: '/thing',
        component: ThingPage
      },
      {
        path: '/other/thing',
        component: OtherThingPage
      },
      { 
        path: '*',
        component: NotFoundPage }
    ]

    var router = new Router({
        mode:'history',
        routes: routes
    })

    export default router
```

When accessing the URL `http://localhost/thing` in the browser, it returns the ThingPage and that is great because I no longer need the hash (`http://localhost/#/thing`).

However, when accessing the URL `http://localhost/other/thing` I get the error `GET http://localhost/other/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`. 
Surprisingly, if I put the # in the URL like `http://localhost/#/other/thing`, it works. I don't know what I'm missing here.

I'm using `publicPath: '/'` in webpack configuration as suggested.

I've no idea what can be causing this.

Comment: can you try shifting your routes to children of root `/`

Comment: Have you set your server config properly as described in the vue docs? https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: What do you mean @NipunJain? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I'm having the trouble in localhost first, @Kielstra. But yeah, I configured nginx for my prod deployment has suggested in that. What I don't get is why I have this problem in localhost.

Comment: @Falcoa What are you serving your app with on your machine then? Might be something in the config of your local config. This is a long shot, but maybe adding `hash: false` to the `new Router()` instantiation is enough.

Comment: @Kielstra, I'm using Django with Gurnicorn. And yes, I tried the hash false with no success...